# How to correctly wrap R function with apply() to implement parallel processing?

Tags: r, function, parallel-processing

I have a function that creates a cartogram of fish catch per country per year and puts that cartogram into a list of cartograms, depending on which year I feed it:

```
fishtogram <- function(year) {
  dfname <- paste0("carto", year) # name of the cartogram being made
  map_year <- get(paste0("map", year), map_years) # 'map_year' contains one SpatialPolygonsDataFrame of a year of fishing/country data pulled from the list of spdf's 'map_years'
  carto_maps[[dfname]] <<- cartogram(map_year, "CATCH", itermax=1) # This is the part that takes forever. Create cartogram named 'dfname', chuck it into the carto_maps list
  plot(carto_maps[[dfname]], main=dfname) # plot it 
  print(paste("Finished", dfname, "at", Sys.time())) # print time finished cartogram
  writeOGR(obj = carto_maps[[dfname]], dsn = "Shapefiles", layer = dfname, driver = "ESRI Shapefile", overwrite_layer=TRUE) # Save cartogram as shapefile
}
```

Originally this was all in a for loop (for the years 1950-2014) and it does the job, just extremely slow. The part that is slowing me down is the `cartogram` function. Currently, producing one cartogram takes about an hour and uses about ~13% of my CPU. I would like to try and use parallel processing to make 3-4 cartograms at once and hopefully speed things up.

How do I wrap this in an apply function correctly to both loop through the years I want and use parallel processing? I've been using [this R bloggers post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/faster-higher-stonger-a-guide-to-speeding-up-r-code-for-busy-people/) for guidance. My attempt:

```
lapply(seq(1975, 2014, 10), fishtogram, .parallel=TRUE)

 >Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : unused argument (.parallel = TRUE)
```

Thank you to @patL in telling me to use `lapply` vs `apply`.

My code & data can be found here: https://github.com/popovs/400m-cartograms/blob/master/400m_cartograms.R

Comment: Try `sapply(seq(1975, 2014, 10), fishtogram)`, not `apply(seq(1975, 2014, 10), 1, fishtogram())`

Comment: `Error in ... : dim(x) must have a positive length`

Comment: Yes definitely! Just pushed the latest to github & added link to my question

Comment: which part is slow? plotting? writing to disk? if it's either of those (i.e. not CPU-bound), then parallelizing might not help you ...

Comment: the `cartogram` function. running that alone takes about an hour. every other part of the `fishtogram` function takes about a second to run. At the moment one cartogram uses ~13% of my CPU and I was hoping to get it to create 3-4 cartograms at once (if that makes sense)

Comment: yes, that makes sense. (You might want to add that information to your question; it shouldn't be buried in the comments)

Comment: @spops I just follow your code and tried `lapply(seq(1975, 2014, 10), fishtogram)` and it works for me. Also tried with `sapply` and also worked. I get this message first: **Mean size error for iteration 1: 671.930983815638**.

Comment: @patL lifesaver! I've updated my question with how to get that to work with parallel processing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go parallel you can try some `parapply` family functions from `parallel` library.

---

Following steps from [this](http://gforge.se/2015/02/how-to-go-parallel-in-r-basics-tips/) page you will need to firs detect the number of cores:

```
library(parallel)

no_cores <- detectCores() - 1 #it is recomendable that you use the number of cores less one

cl <- makeCluster(no_cores) #initiate cluster
```

> It is important to export all functions and objects you will use during your parallelization:

```
clusterExport(cl, "fishtogram")
clusterExport(cl, "dfname")
clusterExport(cl, "map_years")
...
```

Then you can run your parallelized version of `lapply`:

```
parLapply(cl, seq(1975, 2014, 10), fishtogram)
```

and finally stop the cluster

```
stopCluster(cl)
```

---

There are other functions that you can run your code in parallel (`foreach`, from `foreach` library; `mclapply`, also from `parallel` library, etc).

Comment: Hmm, I'm getting this: `Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: cannot coerce type 'S4' to vector of type 'double'` . The Spatial df's are the S4 objects so it appears like a spatial error. But I'm not sure why when trying parallelizing it gives me this error but not simply while running `fishtogram` alone...?

Comment: @spops this error is happening because you didn't export all functions and objects to the cluster (`clusterExport(cl, "...")`). In your code for example, `writeOGR` it is not exported. Remember that everything that your function uses must be exported.

Comment: Ah, you're right. `writeOGR` and `plot` were causing me problems. I also wrapped the libraries using `clusterEvalQ(cl, library(x))`. At this point everything runs in parallel but it produces only `NULL` outputs. I will probably give up on this but thank you for your patience/help!

Comment: @spops Do you get your shapefiles written? Glad to help!

Comment: Wound up using a totally different method, but basically know how to set it up in parallel in the future now. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your specific error is coming from your parenthesis on the fishtogram function. You dont need them when using apply:

```
apply(seq(1975, 2014, 10), 1, fishtogram)
```

..would fix that error.

Comment: When I remove the parentheses: `Error in apply(seq(1975, 2014, 10), 1, fishtogram) : dim(x) must have a positive length`

Comment: I'm not sure what map_years is, so it's hard for me to go deeper.

Comment: I've added a link to my Github - original code is there. `map_years` is a large list of `SpatialPolygonDataFrames`. Each spdf contains polygons of a world map + a dataframe containing fish catch data per one year. So for example, `map_years[["map1950"]]` contains a world map and data on each country's fish catch in the year 1950.

Comment: Try `lapply` instead without the `1,`.